# Cobol JCL error IEW

Tags: cobol, mainframe

Can anyone help me with this Jcl error? It is the only thing stopping my code from compiling and running. It keeps giving back a max CC of 12 even though the code is running perfectly.

```
IEW2736s There is no space left in the directory for DDName Syslmod. Stow of the 
Directory entry member name Strbrk failed.
```

I haven't been able to find a fix for it anywhere , so I feel this is my last hope.

Comment: Please don't re-type messages, but paste. You'll typo something, and we'll waste time. The message is `IEW2736S  THERE IS NO SPACE LEFT IN THE DIRECTORY FOR DDNAME ddname.  STOW OF THE DIRECTORY ENTRY MEMBER NAME member-name FAILED.`, where `ddname` and `member-name` will be your specific case.

Comment: Just to add, this not a JCL error. It is a message from the linkeditor/binder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, the directory for the library on SYSLMOD is full, so your (new) member cannot be added.

If it is a library which you defined yourself, make a copy of the data, ensure the copy worked, then delete and redefine the library with more space for the directory, copy the backed-up data to your newly defined library.

If you are uncertain on how to do these, seek advice from your colleagues/technical support.

If it is not a library that you defined, find out who is responsible for it, and ask that it be extended.

If there are members on the library which you put there and which you no longer need, you can delete (at least one) and continue as a short-term thing.

Comment: Thanks, got it fixed by deleting load modules i was not using and it ran perfectly.